# Did the Jewish people choose G-d, or did G-d choose the Jewish people? Or both?

Tags: theology, am-yisrael-jewish-nation

Did the Jewish people choose G-d, or did G-d choose the Jewish people?  Or both?

Comment: while there are sources that suggest each option, this question might be a bit too philosophical for a definitive answer.

Comment: @resends I didn't realize that.  Thanks.  What if we just stick to what's written in the Torah?

Comment: Without trying to limit what "the Torah" includes, there are still enough events and verses to support a variety of understandings.

Answer (score 6):

Both, according to [the commentary of *Rashi* to Deuteronomy 26:17–18](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9990/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-26.htm#v17).

Comment: one line and spot on target.+1

Answer (score 0):

According to a Midrash (and Maimonides' understanding of it), the patriarch Abraham discovered G-d.[1]

In Laws of Idolatry 1.1-2 Maimonides explains how humans began to worship idols and how Abraham was the first to rediscover G-d. He felt that Abraham was a natural philosopher who came to the realization of G-d’s existence. He recognized that G-d exists, is one, and created all things. He discovered this, as  Prof. Menachem Keller writes, “on the basis of his unaided reason.” Keller adds a footnote “Abraham, that is, came to knowledge of G-d through philosophic conviction, not religious faith.”[2]

Thus, Kellner wrote that "Abraham discovered G-d on his own." This was accomplished by Abraham applying Aristotelian physics, a thorough understanding of the laws of nature, philosophy, and reason.[3] In short, Abraham came to G-d, and not the other way around.

---

Sources:

[1] See TheTorah.com essay called How did [Abraham Discover God](https://www.thetorah.com/article/how-did-abraham-discover-god-the-rationalistic-approach) The Rationalistic Approach

[2] See chapter 2 Chosenness, Not Chauvinism: Maimonides on the Chosen People by Menachem Kellner

[3] A Midrash and tradition says that Abraham discovered G-d through reason and studying the heavens, natural law

Comment: Can you provide the source where Maimonides says this?

Comment: @Alex Give me time. I may be able to bring it to you within an hour.

Comment: @Alex Let me know what u think